# Chapter Style Where All Chapter Numbers Appear Above Chapter Title

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, chapters, tikz-styles

As part of a document I am designing, I would like to create a chapter style that includes all of the chapter numbers in the document. For example, if there are 6 chapters in total, then the numbers 1 through 6 should appear above the chapter title, like so:

[image]

[image]

The numbers should be displayed inside tikz circles, as shown above. The current chapter number should be larger than the rest and highlighted in a blue circle with a dark blue outline. The rest of the circles should be filled with a single horizontal gradient (with a darker gradient for the outlines), making the circles fade from dark gray to white with distance from the blue circle. So far, I have not been able to achieve this and would greatly appreciate some help. Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makechapterstyle{mystyle}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
  \centering\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-.775ex]current bounding box.center)}]
  \node[fill=blue!50,circle,text=white,draw=blue!50!black] {\thechapter};
  \end{tikzpicture}\\[1ex]}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    {\chaptitlefont ##1}}
}
\let\chaptername\relax
%use new chapter style
\chapterstyle{mystyle}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Logarithms}
\chapter{Exponentials}
\chapter{Determinants}
\chapter{Vectors}
\chapter{Differentiation}
\chapter{Integration}
\end{document}
```

Any help in producing the desired output is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting idea. You could do something like this:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\chaptercount}{6}
\makechapterstyle{mystyle}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptername}{}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\huge\sffamily\bfseries}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
  \centering\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (t0) at (0,0);
  \foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {1,...,\chaptercount} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\opacity}{
        \i < \thechapter ? 
            1 / (\chaptercount - 1) * (\chaptercount - (\thechapter - \i)) :
            1 / (\chaptercount - 1) * (\chaptercount + (\thechapter - \i)) 
    }
    \ifnum\thechapter=\i\relax
        \node[
            circle, 
            right={10pt of t\j},
            fill={blue!50},
            draw={blue!50!black},
            text={white},
        ] (t\i) {\i};
    \else
        \node[
            circle, 
            right={10pt of t\j},
            fill=gray!50,
            draw=blue!50!black,
            text=white,
            fill opacity={\opacity},
            font=\small
        ] (t\i) {\i};
    \fi
  }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
  {\chaptitlefont ##1}}
}
%use new chapter style
\chapterstyle{mystyle}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Logarithms}
\chapter{Exponentials}
\chapter{Determinants}
\chapter{Vectors}
\chapter{Differentiation}
\chapter{Integration}
\end{document}
```

Output (after at least two compilations):

[image]
[image]
[image]

If you wish to also fade the node borders, you can just replace `fill opacity` by `opacity`. This will actually fade the text as well, but in this example, the text is white anyways.

The maximum number of chapters is hardcoded using `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\chaptercount}{6}`. It might be possible to get it via other means, but then one always would need to check that the calculations also work with wrong values because during the first compilation cycle the value of `\chaptercount` is likely to be wrong.

Comment: That's a great effort. Is there anything you can do about the outlines on the remaining circles? It'd be good to get them to fade out too.

Comment: @wrb98 Sure, just replace `fill opacity` with `opacity`. Since the text is white, this should work anyways.

Comment: Thanks, that's great.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Very nice Jasper!